# How to increase Time out of Viewdata and Tempdata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ViewData and TempData gets cleared automatically if the page is idle for some time.

The default timeout is too short. how can we increase the timeout of these two collections?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of controlling `ViewData` and `TempData` duration.

`ViewData` is cleared after each request.

`TempData` is kept for the duration of the session - So, if you increased the session duration you could extend the time for which this data is available.

// Expanded Answer
It appears you are trying to use `TempData` to store or persist information.  Although `TempData` exists as long as the session; it is wiped by default on the next request.  It is possible to overwrite this feature and carry forward the `TempData` but that is not what you should be doing.

If you need to persist data for a user; then you should really be using `Session` object.

This is quite simply used as follows

```
string somethingToStore = "This value is to be stored in session";

// Store value to session; it will now persist for the duration of the session
Session["SomeKey"] = somethingToStore;

// To access the stored value
string somethingVal = Session["SomeKey"] as string;
```

Comment: <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2" />
</system.web>
is this right way?

Comment: @AndasHilloans Can I ask why do you need to increase the timeouts? The `ViewData` is a means to pass data from controller to view.  The `TempData` is a means to retain data for a postback or redirect request. If you need to retain data for longer, assign to session or even database.

Comment: @AndasHilloans And yes, that value will alter the length of the session. It is by default 20 minutes I believe.

Comment: TempData use as session my application. thats why we are increase the timeout of tempdata.

Comment: Please suggest any thing else which is replaceable to tempdata.

Comment: @AndasHilloans I have added a basic sample of how to use session.  If you need to persist some information about the user for the duration of a login; then session is what you require.

Comment: thanks for share your experience with me.